# Android gridview by using AsyncTask image loading issue

Tags: android, image, gridview, android-asynctask

I am new to android. I am displaying images in gridview by using AsyncTask. But there are some issues like:

1: onScroll AsyncTask tasks gets call again.
2: Images are not displaying correctly ( Once I scroll it shows top image and load the original latter).

here is my code:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ListRowHolder listRowHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ll_sponsor_list_item,
                        parent, false);
                listRowHolder = new ListRowHolder();
                listRowHolder.imgSponsor = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.imggrid_item_image);
                convertView.setTag(listRowHolder);

            } else {
                listRowHolder = (ListRowHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            try {
                task = new BitmapWorkerTask(listRowHolder.imgSponsor);
                task.image_path = ImageName.get(position);
                task.execute(1);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (thisLogger != null) {
                    thisLogger.error(e.toString());
                    thisLogger.error("\r\n");
                }
            }

            return convertView;
        }



class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

        private String image_path;

        public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }



@Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        try {
            while (running) {
                Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path);
                int width = picture.getWidth();
                int height = picture.getHeight();
                float aspectRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
                int newWidth = 98;
                int newHeight = (int) (98 / aspectRatio);
                Log.v("ImageList", "L");
                return picture = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(picture,
                        newWidth, newHeight, true);

            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (thisLogger != null) {
                thisLogger.error(e.toString());
                thisLogger.error("\r\n");
            }
        }
        return null;

    }


    @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
                    final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                    if (imageView != null) {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }

                }

            }
```

Please let me  know whats wrong here.

Comment: Sure I will do that. Can you please help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: I'm doing something similar HERE!!!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808114/picasso-loading-of-image-spawned-inside-asynctask